# Convert columns to rows and repeat row labels in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I am trying to convert table 1 to the format in table 2. How can I do it in google sheets ?
Thank you very much.

Table 1 -

[image]

Table 2 -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 A3:A&"×"&B2:E2&"×"&TEXT(B1:E1, "dd/mm")&"×"&B3:E), "×")), 
 "where Col4 is not null", ))
```

[image]